# Is there a create/add event for layers in Leaflet and how to capture it?

Tags: javascript, events, leaflet, event-handling

I can't figure out what event is triggered whenever I add an item (marker, polygon etc.) using `Leaflet.PM` (through the Geoman plugin) to a layer.

Using

```
map.on('pm:remove', (e) => { });
```

I can for example detect a remove event (coming from the polygon manager, previously added to the map). I am also able to detect `edit` events. I tried `pm:create` and `pm:add` but nothing happens.

Also none of those event handlers (even the ones that are working) appear to work when assigned to a layer:

```
layer.on(...)
```

Even when adding a geometry to the layer programmatically (using `mygeometry.addTo(layer)`), I cannot trigger any of the above mentioned event handlers.

I know I can assign an event listener to the geometry itself, which I also currently do for a `mouseover` event for my markers to show a popup with some info about the marker. I am not sure how such an event listener would handle e.g. deletion of the object it is assigned to.

Which event am I supposed to listen to and how do I add an event listener for creation/adding of any drawn item on a layer level?

Answer (score 0):

Below you have some examples:

```
map.on("pm:drawstart", function (e) {
  console.log("drawstart", e);
});

map.on("pm:drawend", function (e) {
  console.log("drawend", e);
});

map.on("pm:create", function (e) {
  console.log("create", e);

  // listen to changes on the new layer
  e.layer.on("pm:edit", function (x) {
    console.log("edit", x);
  });
});
```